# Flexslider off screen in firefox

Tags: html, css, flexslider

I am making a website for my friends restaurant and I am implementing the Flexslider plug in.
When I view it in IE and Chrome there is no problem, but when i view it in firefox it seems to be almost 50% off screen.

Here is a demo, I tried making a fiddle but i cant seem to get it working at all.

[Demo](http://www.digitalerawebdesign.com/cavo/index.html)

Edit: sorry for the unoptimized images

Comment: Well, you have invalid HTML. Check you page with [validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: I believe @Vucko means this: `<stong class="logo pull-left">` needs to be this: `<strong class="logo pull-left">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your h1 has display: inline-block.  That needs to be block:

```
.logo h1 {
    font-size: 2.8em;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Why should it be `block`? Just because this "fixes" the problem, doesn't mean that this is the solution. The OP has invalid HTML so he can start with there.

Comment: this worked great thanks alot! 

@Vucko even with the fixed html it happened.
im pretty sure it is due to my "logo" dipping down into my slider due to the "inline-block" property.

Comment: @Vucko yes, he can start there if he wants.  And then change the display as I recommended to fix the issue regarding the image being off the screen - which was his question. Ultimately the 'solution' would answer his question (display: block) then make any additional suggestions, if desired.